# How can I make my android app appears in Google search

Tags: android, google-search, deep-linking

When you search some special keywords in google, within the normal results, sometimes android apps also appear... how can I make my android apps to appear in google search (I am not talking about deep linking)

Answer (score 0):

I think if your app have been downloaded like 5k+(simply an eg) in play store , in the sense your application is becoming popular then it will be automatically shown in the Google search.Else if you search with your app name ,i guess it will show up with the play store link.

Answer (score 0):

put a proper description to your application, your application should already appear with it's full name, put some short description too and you could actually think of using ads. But if you want your application to just come out when a similar thing is written, it should be downloaded many times.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look [here](https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/index.html)
 It says basically

> To enable Google Search app indexing, you need to provide Google with information about the relationship between your app and web site. This process involves the following steps:
>   Enable deep linking to specific content in your app by adding intent filters in your app manifest.
>   Annotate these links in the associated web pages on your web site or in a Sitemap file.
>   Opt in to allow Googlebot to crawl through your APK in the Google Play store to index your app content. You are automatically opted-in when you join as a participant in the early adopter program.